# How can i rewrite PHP while loop in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I am new to Laravel. I have a loop written in PHP, but I'm trying to redevelop it for use in a Laravel Blade. So I have this piece of code I am finding difficult to translate. I can pass `$data` from the controller, but how do I write the below code in the view?

```
while ($data = $result1->fetch_array()) {
    $dataCount = $data['colCount'];

    for ($x = 0; $x <= $dataCount; $x++) {
        echo "<ul><li>
            <label>
                <input type='radio' name='project-1-response[".$i."]' 
                    value='' />
                    <h7>".$data[$x]."</h7>
            </label> 
            </li></ul>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#loops

Comment: Unless you made a custom h7 element, I'm pretty sure those don't exist.

Answer (score 2):

For the most part it's pretty straightforward.

- Replace `while(condition) { ... }` with 
  `@while(condition) ... @endwhile`.
- Replace `for(init; condition; increment) { ... }` with 
  `@for(init; condition; increment) ... @endfor`.
- Wrap your php statements in `@php ... @endphp` or if it's a single statement , 
  use the `@php(statement)` syntax.
- Use brackets to echo out variables or functions in your markup. (`{{ $variable }}`, `{{ count($array) }}`).

You end up with

```xml
@while($data = $result1->fetch_array())
    @php($dataCount = $data['colCount'])
    @for($x = 0; $x <= $dataCount; $x++)
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="project-1-response[{{ $i }}]" value="" />
                    <h7>{{ $data[$x] }}</h7>
                </label> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    @endfor
@endwhile
```

IF `$data` is an array, you could use the `@foreach` loop instead. You also have access to the `$loop` variable there.